# Can I put multiple download links in same table cell in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using shiny and I'm having trouble inserting multiple links in the same table cell. Every link should allow the user to download local files found on the computer.
Here is an image of what I mean:
[table with links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR9Qa.png)

For columns 2, 3, and 4, whose rows include at most only 1 link, it works perfectly; when I click on the hyperlinks I am able to download the corresponding file from my pc. However, for column 5, which includes multiple hyperlinks in each cell, I am unable to do so. Clicking on the links returns nothing; no file is downloaded (but I don't get an error).

This is the code I'm using for column 5:

```
lapply(1:nrow(table), function(i) {
 if (table[i,5]!="No panels")
    {
      panels=strsplit(table[i,5], "<br>")
      panels=panels$`Gene panel`
      for (j in 1:length(panels)){
      output[[paste0("downloadData", i, j, 4)]] <- downloadHandler( # as opposed to before, I added here another variable 'j' in the name of the output variable to differentiate between the different panels for each sample name
        filename=paste("./Gene_panel/", table[i,1], "_", panels[j], sep=""),  
        content = function(file) {
          file.copy(paste("./Gene_panel/", table[i,1], "_", panels[j], sep=""), file)
        }
      )}}
    }
  )

output$hidden_downloads_panel <- renderUI(
    lapply(1:nrow(table), function(i) {
      if (table[i,5]!="No panels"){
      panels=strsplit(table[i,5], "<br>")
      panels=panels$`Gene panel`
      for (j in 1:length(panels)){
      downloadLink(paste0("downloadData", i, j, 4), "download", class = "hiddenLink") # also added 'j' here
      }
      }
    }))

  output$table <- renderDataTable({ # here, it's the same as before but I just added the last '%>% mutate' to accommodate the last column 'Gene panel'
    table=as.data.frame(table)%>%
      mutate("Quality Control" = lapply(1:n(),
                           function(i)
                           { if (table[i,2]=="Yes"){
                             paste0('<a href="#" onClick=document.getElementById("downloadData',i, 1,'").click() >Yes</a>')}
                             else 
                               paste0("No")}
      ))%>% mutate("BWA" = lapply(1:n(),
                                  function(i)
                                  { if (table[i,3]=="Yes"){
                                    paste0('<a href="#" onClick=document.getElementById("downloadData',i,2, '").click() >Yes</a>')}
                                    else 
                                      paste0("No")}))%>% mutate("Annotation" = lapply(1:n(),
                              function(i)
                              { if (table[i,4]=="Yes"){
                                paste0('<a href="#" onClick=document.getElementById("downloadData',i,3, '").click() >Yes</a>')}
                                else 
                                  paste0("No")}))%>% mutate("Gene panel" = lapply(1:n(),
                                     function(i)
     if (table[i,5]!="No panels"){
        panels=strsplit(table[i,5], "<br>")   
        panels=panels$`Gene panel`
        list=c()
        for (j in 1:length(panels))
        {
        list=append(list,paste0('<a href="#" onClick=document.getElementById("downloadData', i, j, 4, '").click() >', panels[j], '</a>')) 
        }
        paste0(list, collapse="<br>")
      }
    else
      paste0("No panels")                 
))
    table
  }, escape = F)
```

In case something is missing or you need further clarification, I asked this question in more detail (with my code) on the rstudio forum (haven't received an answer though): https://community.rstudio.com/t/multiple-links-in-same-table-cell/110558

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "I am unable to do so" or  "it's not working" (in your other post), what is the wrong behavior or error message? Please provide the code of your app here as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. By "it's not working", I mean nothing happens when I click on the hyperlinks. There's no error, but nothing gets downloaded. And no problem, I added the code here as well.

Comment: It's difficult without the possibility to test the app with the full code and some example data. It could be related to the for loop not generating unique IDs for each link ([see this](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/)) and need to use `local()`, but I guess you would get at least one download link working. Can you check the generated IDs of each downloadLink in your browser (F12 on Firefox or Chrome)?

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure each link has its unique ID, but I don't know how to get it using F12 (I tried but couldn't find any link). However I did try to `print(i, j, panels[j])` at every  `for (j in 1:length(panels))`, and I got the same numbers with the corresponding gene panels all 3 times. For example, I got "11EPILEPSY GENE PANEL.csv", then "12INTELLECTUAL DISABILITY GENE PANEL.csv:, etc... in every loop. Hope this is helpful. If using F12 would make us know for sure that the loop is generating unique IDs, can you please let me know where to find the links? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser, usually using F12, or in the tools menu, or right-click on your app and select "inspect". Then you can access the HTML source code generated by Shiny ([Firefox Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector) or [Chrome Elements](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom/)), try to find each link ID. With the selector icon in the top left corner (node picker) you can select the right code just by hovering the corresponding element in the page.

Comment: I found the links, and the ID's are all correct. Here is an example:
`<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;downloadData144&quot;).click()">METABOLIC DISORDERS GENE PANEL.csv</a>`
So that's probably not the problem right? Is it possible that the `paste0(list, collapse="<br>")` is the problem?

Comment: ok so this part is well rendered but I would have guessed that the problem is in generating the hidden `downloadLink`s with the for loop, we need to find out if those are uniques. Can you try using `local()` inside the for loop like [in this example](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/)?

Comment: you need to check if the hidden links are generated, can you find the links with the css class hiddenLink in the page? (`<a id="downloadData114">`, `<a id="downloadData124">`...)

Comment: Actually no they're not generated! There's hidden links for columns 2, 3, 4 but not 5. Does that mean the error is in `output$hidden_downloads_panel=renderUI{...}`? I added local() before `downloadLink(paste0("downloadData", i, j, 4)...` but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it by replacing the for loop with `lapply` in the `renderUI` part and generating the `downloadLink` as a `tagList`:

```
  output$hidden_downloads_panel <- renderUI({
outputlist <- lapply(1:nrow(table), function(i) {
  if (table[i,5]!="No panels"){
    panels=strsplit(table[i,5], "<br>")
    panels=panels[[1]]
    lapply(1:length(panels), function(j){
      tagList(
      downloadLink(paste0("downloadData", i, j, 4), "download", class = "hiddenLink")
      )
    })
      }
  })
})
```

and putting the `downloadHandler` outputs in a local environment to generate unique IDs with the for loop:

```
  lapply(1:nrow(table), function(i) {
if (table[i,5]!="No panels")
{
  panels=strsplit(table[i,5], "<br>")
  panels=panels[[1]]
  for (j in 1:length(panels)){
    local({
      my_j = j
    output[[paste0("downloadData", i, my_j, 4)]] <- downloadHandler( 
      filename=paste("./Gene_panel/", table[i,1], "_", panels[my_j], sep=""),  
      content = function(file) {
        file.copy(paste("./Gene_panel/", table[i,1], "_", panels[my_j], sep=""), file)
      }

    )
    })
    }}
})
```

I had to replace your `panels=panels$"Gene panel"` line with `panels=panels[[1]]` to make it work with my test dataframe, I was able to "display" the 6 hidden links of your example data.

Comment: (I know stackoverflow doesn't like these kinds of comments but) I'm on the verge of tears. I've been trying to fix this for weeks, and it just worked. I have a meeting about my Shiny interface tomorrow and was stressed about this issue. You're a hero. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Good to hear! Good luck for your meeting